# Link not work in Framework 7 with Template 7

Tags: html-framework-7

I have enable automatically compile all Template7 in `my-app.js`:

```
var myApp = new Framework7({
    template7Pages: true, //enable Template7 rendering for pages
    // Automatically compile all Template7
    precompileTemplates: true,
});
```

Then initial and compile:

```
var context = {
    detail:[
    { firstname:'Joe',lastname:'John'
    },
    { firstname:'Joe',lastname:'John'
    },
]};
var html = Template7.templates.peoples(context);
$$('.people-page').html(html);
```

And in my `index.html`,

```
<div id="tabpeople" class="view tab">
    <div class="pages">
        <div data-page="home-1" class="page people-page">
            <script id="peoples" type="text/template7">
                <div class="page-content">
                    <div class="content-block-title">Welcome To Framework7</div>
                    <div class="content-block"><a href="about.html" class="button">About Framework7</a></div>
```

And it cannot link to `about.html`, anyone have advices ?